# How Do Schema migration in mongoose & mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, migration, mongoose-schema

I would like to know how to perform schema migration in Mongoose and MongoDB. I've tried searching for resources on the internet, but I couldn't find a clear example. Could you please provide an example code and explain how to do it? Also, if possible, please advise on how to handle schema migration in production environments